# Reading CSV with WKT column straight into a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame with geometries

Tags: python, geopandas, well-known-text

Is there a good way to read CSVs that contain a WKT column straight into a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame?

I've seen several solutions that take a two-step approach:

1. Read the CSV into a Pandas DataFrame
2. Pass the DataFrame to GeoPandas and use `shapely.wkt.loads()` to generate the actual geometries

I'm trying to avoid this two-step process and find a way to do this in one single step. However, the approach I use feels a little dirty and I just wanted to see if there's a better/more efficient way to do it. Here is a reproducible example where both approaches are showcased:

### Reproducible example

```
# Loading libraries needed
import shapely
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

# Making mock CSV file
csv_filename = 'temp.csv'

(pd.DataFrame(data={"ids":[1,2,3],
                    "wkt_geom":['POINT (1 1)',
                                'POINT (2 2)',
                                'POINT (3 3)']})
 .to_csv(csv_filename, index=False))

# Two-step approach
df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df, 
                       geometry=df['wkt_geom']
                       .apply(shapely.wkt.loads))

# One-step approach
gdf = (gpd.read_file(csv_filename)
       .assign(geometry=lambda _df: shapely.wkt.loads(_df['wkt_geom']))
       .set_geometry('geometry'))
```

#### Streamlining the one-step approach

The one-step approach I showed above feels a little janky: it relies on the `assign` command and then requires me to use the `set_geometry` command.

Is there a more direct way we can read a CSV file containing a WKT column straight into a GeoPandas GeoDataFrame in such a way that the WKT column gets automatically parsed?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoSeries.from_wkt.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv(csv_filename)
print(df)
    ids     wkt_geom
0    1  POINT (1 1)
1    2  POINT (2 2)
2    3  POINT (3 3)



s = gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(df.wkt_geom)
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=df, geometry=s)
print(gdf)
     ids     wkt_geom          geometry
 0    1  POINT (1 1)  POINT (1.00000 1.00000)
 1    2  POINT (2 2)  POINT (2.00000 2.00000)
 2    3  POINT (3 3)  POINT (3.00000 3.00000)
```

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot about the `from_wkt` method! This is great, thank you!!! I see that your solution takes the multi-step approach here of loading the CSV into a DF and then using that DF to make a GDF. Do you see a way of using a one-shot approach for that? The only solution I could think of also used the `assign` and `set_geometry` methods: `gpd.read_file(csv_filename).assign(geom=lambda _df: gpd.GeoSeries.from_wkt(_df['wkt_geom'])).set_geometry('geom')`

Comment: Why do you want to use  `.assign`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wasn't clear with my comment. I don't **want** to use `assign`. I just don't know how to perform a one-line process without using it. And my question in my last comment was geared towards: is it possible to do this in one step **without** the `assign` command? Sorry for the lack of clarity =)